# Fill Razr Select with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#

I am populating a select element with javascript inside a razor form.Is there any way when submitting the form to determine the selected element?I prefer using razor syntax (DisplayFor/EditorFor) on  the fields of the model.If i can't i will be forced to abandon the razor syntax and autogenerate all the fields.

**JavaScript**

```
 function fillCombo(comboid,options)
    {
       $.each(options,function(index,elem){
        $("#"+comboid).append(new Option(elem.Name,elem.ID));
       })
}
```

**View**

```
@using AdminMVC.Models
@using AdminMVC.ConfigConstants
@model AdminMVC.Models.Location

<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/edit.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var activities=@Html.Raw(ViewData[Constants.ViewData.TActivities]);
                var comboName="cmbAct";
                fillCombo(comboName,activities);
            });
              </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="form">

        </div>
        <div id="page">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("Edit","Location",FormMethod.Post))
        {
            <label >Select Activity:</label>
            <div id="cmbActivities">
            **<select id="cmbAct"> //is there any way to get the selected element 
            </select>**
            </div>
            <div id="table">
            <label>Set Location:</label>
            <table border="">

               @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.Id)
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>Model.Name)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(x=>Model.Name)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>Model.Type)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(x=>Model.Type)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayNameFor(x=>Model.Description)</td>
                <td>@Html.EditorFor(x=>Model.Description)</td>
            </tr>

             </table>
             </div>
             <div id="control-panel">
            <input type="submit" value="Edit">
            </div>
        }
    </body>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you trying to store the selected value in Razor or JavaScript?

Comment: I  would like to keep the razor syntax for generation and editor of fields if possible.But at the same time i need to send in the response the value of the selected item in the combobox.

Comment: Why mix, why can't you do an html select, with razor looping to build option / value then just use JavaScript Ajax?

Comment: I used a html select and a js function to generate the options.But the selected option has to be embedded with the rest of the fields because they belong to the same object. I want to send in the body of the request the fields and the selected option.